Installed bind as a local DNS server, not sure it's being used. How do I verify?
I've installed bind as my dns server on a small local network. Now how do I demonstrate on my other workstations that it is indeed being used?
The installation had instructions as you configured bind to verify that it is at least configured correctly.
My reason for being a bit paranoid about it is that I have a router in which I've made the various workstations operate with a static IPv4 address. When I ping the various workstations from other sources am I indeed seeing the DNS working (I've added the DNS addresses into the network manager dialogs) or am I getting some simple name resolution from the default route?
I was in the "resolv.conf" file and read the comments and ran the suggested command:
resolvectl status

Here is the output:
jdowd@neptune:~$ sudo resolvectl status
[sudo] password for jdowd: 
Global
         Protocols: -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
  resolv.conf mode: stub

Link 2 (eno1)
    Current Scopes: none
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 3 (wlp0s20f3)
    Current Scopes: none
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Link 4 (br0)
    Current Scopes: DNS
         Protocols: +DefaultRoute -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported
Current DNS Server: 192.168.101.1
       DNS Servers: 192.168.101.1
        DNS Domain: lan

Link 5 (docker0)
    Current Scopes: none
         Protocols: -DefaultRoute -LLMNR -mDNS -DNSOverTLS DNSSEC=no/unsupported

Now link 4 (of which 2 is the slave) is the one that I'm worried about.
My DNS is running on a Ubuntu server: 22.04LTS and my various workstations are running: Ubuntu 24.04LTS
Thanks for any help in advance.
Cheers!!
